# SQL Server [Express] Instance name mapping?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to map a sql server instance name to something else? Not asking about changing the name of an instance, simply, re routing a requested name to the actual name, sort of like a name-value pair.

I have a sql express installation with a machine_name\SQLEXPRESS naming convention, but I want 'localhost' to work. I don't want to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **Aliases** to your instance in **sql server configuration tool**. See detail in link below.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29e88414-265e-4912-a8e5-04bda99528fc/cannot-access-local-sql-server-2008-instance-via-localhost-?forum=sqltools

Comment: This was excellent, thank you! FWIW I had to enable the named pipe protocol under SQL Server Network Configuration.